# How can I read both Int64 and Int32 values using Database.SqlQuery<>

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, dbcontext

I've wrote a function to check if specific ID exist in a table using schema name and name of table as input parameters.

Query which I created to execute on database will return -2 if it cannot find record with given ID and return its ID if item is found.

```
private long isThisNodeAlreadyInsertedInDatabaseByHeadquarter(
    string schemaName
    string tableName,
    string primaryNodeId,
    string primaryKeyFieldName){

    string targetTableName = $"{schemaName}.{tableName}";
    string sqlCommandString2 = $"select COALESCE(MAX({primaryKeyFieldName}),-2)" + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                             $"from {targetTableName}" + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                              "WHERE " + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                               $"{primaryKeyFieldName}={foundID}";
    //will return -2 if not found otherwise return its id
    DbRawSqlQuery<Int64> result2 = rawDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Int64>(sqlCommandString2);
    long foundID = result2.Single();
    return foundID;
}
```

My Problem is that some primary keys in my database are of type `Int` and some are of type `BigInt` which are equivalent to `Int32` and `Int64`  in C# respectively (or `int` and `long` respectively).

When I read primary keys of tables of type BigInt nothing wrong happens but when I want to read primary keys of table which are of type Int it causes exception:

> {"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the
>   'System.Int64' type is not valid."}

Although it is possible to store int in long variables, casting `Int32` to `Int64` in `Database.SqlQuery` causes this exception.
I want to know are there any workarounds for this situation or I only have to read values using `SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert PK to `BIGINT` in query and read as `Int64`:

```
"select CONVERT(BIGINT,COALESCE(MAX({primaryKeyFieldName}),-2))"
```

Also, you can replace `COALESCE` with `ISNULL` function:

```
"select CONVERT(BIGINT,ISNULL(MAX({primaryKeyFieldName}),-2))"
```

Comment: From the title of the method I would have thought an If Exists would be faster.